# Match two words not having a specific word between them

Tags: regex

I need to find all combinations of two words, say `from` and `to`, not having a particular word between them, say `exclude`

```
from
exclude
to

from
include
to
```

Only the second from -> to should match. Currently I can do this but just excluding single characters

`from([^x]*?)to`

Comment: you probably want a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: How strictly should the words be matched? Would `excluded` be OK or not? What about `fromage` or `today` - should they count as start/end markers, too?

Comment: Tim I'm looking for exact words match. So they won't be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

> When to Use this Technique
>   Suppose our boss now tells us that we still want to match up to and including {END}, but that we also need to avoid stepping over a `{MID}` section, if it exists. Starting with the lazy dot-star version to ensure we match up to the `{END}` delimiter, we can then temper the dot to ensure it doesn't roll over `{MID}`:

```
{START}(?:(?!{MID}).)*?{END}
```

> If more phrases must be avoided, we just add them to our tempered dot:

```
 {START}(?:(?!{MID})(?!{RESTART}).)*?{END}
```

> This is a useful technique to know about.

Use

```
from((?:(?!exclude|to|from).)*)to
```

Use DOTALL modifier if you need the dot to match newlines.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jW9cK2/2)

See a related [SO thread about a *tempered greedy token*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).